# Sharing video into facebook messenger

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm trying to share video via facebook messenger using code

```
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

            FBSDKShareVideo *video = [FBSDKShareVideo new];
            video.videoURL = assetURL;
            FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
            content.video = video;

            FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];
            messageDialog.delegate = self;
            [messageDialog setShareContent:content];

            if ([messageDialog canShow])
            {
                [messageDialog show];
            }
        }];
```

application shows facebook messenger window with recipients list, but when I select them, "send" button remains inactive.

[image]

In delegate methods I did not get errors. All seems good, but I can't send message.

after line

```
content.video = video;
```

all seems good:

```
(lldb) po video.videoURL
assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=A0F1A001-375B-4708-B2F3-E2CFAFB213A6&ext=mov

(lldb) po content
<FBSDKShareVideoContent: 0x159046b0>

(lldb) po content.video
<FBSDKShareVideo: 0x159533d0>
```

when I'm trying to send link - all works good:

```
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

            FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
            content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
            content.contentTitle = @"title";
            content.contentDescription = @"description";

            FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];
            messageDialog.delegate = self;
            [messageDialog setShareContent:content];

            if ([messageDialog canShow])
            {
                [messageDialog show];
            }
        }];
```

[image]

and for facebook sharing in same class it works good:

```
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

            FBSDKShareVideo *video = [FBSDKShareVideo new];
            video.videoURL = assetURL;
            FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [FBSDKShareVideoContent new];
            content.video = video;

            [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self.controller withContent:content delegate:self];
        }];
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be the same issue as described here https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/941685909187364/

Comment: facing same issue, please let us know if you have been fixed